# How to save different Cppcheck results in a same Xml file

Tags: xml, cppcheck

I am already doing cppcheck path.c --xml-version=2 2> path2.xml. the thing is that i want to do several cppchecks in different files but I want to sabe then in a single xml file is possible. I do not know if this has lot of sense, because maybe you lose information about the paths of the errors. But if there is answer I would be interested on knowing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am a Cppcheck developer. There is not any builtin solution right now in Cppcheck.

possibly you could use some script.

if you can somehow create a compile_commands.json file then you can analyze all the files at once. I think that would be good. It is possible you can use the processor cores more effectively then, and also you can use "cppcheck build dir" to get whole program analysis.